# Lack of access to Android folders to save files in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a button in my application by which the user selects a path to save my database in that path.
But in my code only the user has access to the download folder. And if you choose another path, the following message will appear, which is apparently due to lack of access.
Please guide me to get access to all folders.

error

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathAccessException: Cannot copy file to '/storage/emulated/0//cca_customers_1688370606908.db', path = '/data/user/0/com.example.cca/databases/cca_customers.db' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)`

````
` ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final dbFolder = await getDatabasesPath();
                File source1 = File('$dbFolder/cca_customers.db');

                Directory? selectedDirectory;
                Directory? directory = selectedDirectory;
                directory ??= Directory(FolderPicker.rootPath);
                Directory? newDirectory = await FolderPicker.pick(
                    allowFolderCreation: true,
                    context: context,
                    rootDirectory: directory,
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))));
                selectedDirectory = newDirectory;
                String? appDocumentsDirectory = selectedDirectory!.path;
                if (appDocumentsDirectory.isNotEmpty) {
                  Directory backupDirectory = Directory(appDocumentsDirectory);
                  if (!(await backupDirectory.exists())) {
                    await backupDirectory.create(recursive: true);
                  }

                  String timestamp =
                      DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
                  String newPath =
                      "${backupDirectory.path}/cca_customers_$timestamp.db";
// encryption
                  await source1.copy(newPath);
                  await encryptFile(newPath);
                  

                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg:
                        "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.t_Backup_file_path} $newPath",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  );
                } else {
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                        .t_Backup_failed_Please_check_software_access_to_memory,
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  );
                }
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.green),
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.t_Data_Backup),`
            )```
````